# Adding Signalr version 2.2.0 nuget package raises error "Sequence contains more than one element" in UAP projects

Tags: signalr, signalr.client, win-universal-app, windows-10

With the Windows 10 Technical Preview tools, attempting adding the latest version of SignalR to Universal App Platform projects results in the error:

```
"Sequence contains more than one element".
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the previous version (2.1.2) works with one caveat: After building the application Visual Studio will prompt with the error:

```
Unable to activate Windows Store app
The {application} process started, but the activation
request failed with error 'The app didn't start'.
```

This because the package adds **app.config** to the project, making references to its dependencies. Deleting **app.config** , allows the project to build and run.